# Is it possible to query by populate document in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I also tried in mongoose doc and MongoDB community but I couldn't find any solution.

[image: How can i query document by populated document?]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an aggregation pipeline in order to achieve this. The following code will perform the lookup (same as `populate`) first and then match on the populated fields:

```
const story = await Story.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "authors",
      "localField": "author",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "author"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "author.name": "Ian Fleming"
    }
  }
])
```